# Serious troubles with my loadgame/savegame method

Tags: c#, debugging, methods, game-development

I'm trying to develop a text based game in C#. I am having a real tough time getting my load game to allow me to load the player, and my save game to save more than one time.

It's also not saving the player name. I've debugged for around 5 hours with no success... here's the code:

```
    public static void saveGame()
    {
        PlayerClass p = new PlayerClass();
        //creates bin folder named textadsaves with player id
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        string path = "textgameSaves/" + p.id + ".sf";

        //creates file in bin folder with player name or id and closes file
        FileStream file = File.Open(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate);
        binForm.Serialize(file,p);
        file.Close();
    }

    public static PlayerClass loadGame( out bool newP)
    {
        newP = false;
        string gameSaves = "textgameSaves";
        Console.Clear();
        Console.WriteLine("Choose your Save Game.");
        //to select from a list of saves
        string[] paths = Directory.GetFiles(gameSaves);
        //convert paths into a player instance(file)
        List<PlayerClass> players = new List<PlayerClass>();
        int idCount = 0;
        BinaryFormatter binForm = new BinaryFormatter();
        //check every path 
        foreach (string p in paths)
        {
            FileStream file = File.Open(p, FileMode.Open);
            PlayerClass player = (PlayerClass)binForm.Deserialize(file);
            file.Close();
            players.Add(player);
        }
        //check for player save
        idCount = players.Count;
        while (true)
        {
            Console.Clear();
            Console.WriteLine("Choose your player");
            foreach (PlayerClass p in players)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(p.id + ": " + p.name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Please enter player name or id. (id:# or playername).\n Additionally 'Create' will start a new save.");
            string[] data = Console.ReadLine().Split(':');
            try
            {
                if (data[0]== "id")
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(data[1], out int id))
                    {
                        foreach(PlayerClass player in players)
                        {
                            if(player.id == id)
                            {
                                return player;
                            }
                        }
                        Console.Clear();
                        Console.WriteLine("not finding the character in file.\n press enter");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Your id needs a number\n press enter to continue");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
                else if (data[0] =="create")
                {
                    PlayerClass newPlayer = startFun(idCount);
                    newP = true;
                    return newPlayer;

                }
                else
                {
                    foreach(PlayerClass player in players)
                    {
                        if(player.name == data[0])
                        {
                            return player;
                        }
                    }
                    Console.Clear();
                    Console.WriteLine("Not finding player in file.\n press enter");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }
            }
            catch(IndexOutOfRangeException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Your id needs a number\n press enter to continue");
                Console.ReadKey();
            }
        }
```

Comment: But you are serializing a `new PlayerClass()`. I expect `p.id` to be null in this case. You need to pass your active `PlayerClass` instance to the `saveGame()` method and serialize this.

Comment: Your provided haste bin code, is not really what is needed to reproduce the precise error, nor have you provided the precise exception message, nor do you show what you have tried, other than mentioning you have been debugging for 5 hours. 

You should read the "how to ask a question section, and redo this question".

Comment: ``` PlayerClass``` is serialized id shouldnt be null its an instance in PlayerClass. I guess I may be confused. Do you have an example?

Comment: don't link to external code when you can embed it easily here

Answer (score 0):

Your biggest problem is right at the top of your `SaveGame` method:

```
PlayerClass p = new PlayerClass();
```

You're instantiating a new player, and then trying to save it. **You're not actually saving the players in your game.**

What you want to do instead is to get a list of every player in your game, and save each of them, similar to what you do when loading those players.